# How to decide how many Exceptions should be thrown?

Tags: java, exception, methods

I have some (few) methods that throws six or seven different Exceptions, that are caused by similar but not equals events. All of the seven Exception are handled in another method, that thanks to these many exceptions can show specific messages.

Is it ok this way or should I reduce the number of exceptions thrown?

Comment: Do you need to handle them differently depending on which type is thrown? (bearing in mind that the exceptions can include error messages)

Comment: If you name is Bob, then you only throw a max of `"Bob".length ()` Exceptions - If you want more change your name to a longer name

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer;  you are the judge of whether the differences are sufficient to merit the creation of new classes.  For myself, if I find myself based on solely the information you have provided where the exceptions are not handled any differently, I would seriously consider a single exception.   Eg, if these are form validation methods, instead of a “FormMissingNameException”, “FormMissingAddressException”, etc I would go with a single “FormInvalid” exception (although personally I would also avoid exceptions for form validations)

Comment: Ok thanks, it is something similar to the forms example!